# Is it fallacious to argue "you can't say X because you lack authority"?

Tags: fallacies

So I understand an Argument from Authority, or *ad verecundiam*, fallacy is where someone uses a persons/their authority to reason their argument without other sound evidence. But what in a situation like this:

Person A: What is the maximum sentence someone can get for assault?

Person B: According to this state's revised code, assault is a Misdemeanor I with a maximum jail sentence of 180 days and max fine of $2500.

Person C: You're not a lawyer or cop Person B, you don't know what you're talking about!

Why is Person C's argument fallacious? Is a lack of an authoritative position reason to void an argument?

Comment: Welcome to philosophy.SE! That you could see the argument is *fallacious*, but can't immediately name it as a *fallacy* is the more important move...

Comment: Thank you @MoziburUllah what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Well the correct thing to thing to do is to examine why it is you judged the argument to be fallacious - to give your account - to name it as a fallacy is simply to name that kind of account; however there are many kinds of account, and not all of them get to have names.

Comment: Please see http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/3040/sample-guide-what-is-the-name-of-fallacy-a-implies-b-therefore-c . It's really not important to *name* fallacies.

Comment: The above comments are all excellent advice - to answer your question, "why is Person C's argument fallacious", a first pass would go: C is assuming that a formal position is necessary for certain knowledge, while in fact there is no requirement to be formally involved in law to know law.

Comment: The above comments are great advice @commando it is why I changed the question from asking the name of the fallacy to why the argument is fallacious. To your answer then I could then ask (devil's advocate of course) if there is no requirement to be formally involved in law to understand it and give advice on the subject (which one could say Person B is doing) then why in society is a person who is not an attorney giving legal advice in a public manner so frowned upon?

Comment: @commando For example, if I had a website and I put some kind of legal advice on it, I would be (as I'm not a lawyer) obliged to disclaim that my advice should not be substituted for an attorney's advice for serious legal matters, no matter how well researched my advice is

Comment: @Douglas_Symb that would be because while your lack of formal documentation is not proof of your ignorance, you similarly lack socially sanctioned proof of *competence*, and it is considered improper to offer advice on something so serious when you can't prove that you know (where the proof is indirect - having a J.D. is *supposed* to mean you're competent).

Comment: @commando so what you're saying (if I'm applying your logic correctly) is that Person C is fallacious because he or she is declaring that Person B is *ignorant*, where as while Person B would not be proper to represent, or even assist in representation in any formal legal situation in which Person A is involved with, his or her lack of socially sanctioned competence is not at all correlated with his or her knowledge, or lack of, on the subject?

Comment: @Douglas_Symb that's a nice and clear way of phrasing what I was trying to say, yes =)

Comment: Why thank you @commando. I would like to see your argument as an answer to this post!

Comment: B might have been not a lawyer, nor a cop (who wouldn't know that kind of thing anyway), but someone who was in court accused of assault, who then listened very closely to what the judge, prosecutor, and defense lawyer had to say about the subject. Or a relative of such a person. Or just generally curious and picking up bits of information everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what I would call this fallacy but I would say we can generalize the problem as confusing credentials with knowledge.

In other words, it doesn't matter what letters come before or after someone's name as to whether or not they might know (or not something).

At first, I want to say this is an informal fallacy, but I think we can actually describe it as a formal fallacy.

First off, I think we can reorganize the argument as follows:

1. If you were a lawyer, you would (could) know what you are talking about.
2. You are not a lawyer.
3. Ergo, you do not know what you are talking about.

This is a **formally fallacious** argument that is an example of "denying the antecedent." The fallacy is that there are of a number of ways that an individual could know what they are talking about which is not restricted to "lawyer" (substitute as necessary). In this case, the conditional identifies a sufficient condition.

In terms of informal fallacies happening in the argument, I suppose we could name this either an *ad hominem* insofar as it does not deny the claim of C but only attacks C's ability to make the claim or still an "argument from authority" or possibly an inverted argument for authority (to mark that the assertion is that an authority is necessary and absent).

Similar arguments need not necessarily be fallacious. For instance,

1. * If you speak Japanese, you understand what he is saying.
2. You don't speak Japanese.
3. Ergo, you don't understand what he is saying.

But here the language is deceptive, because in general we would take the first claim here not to be a simple conditional but rather a claim that is a *necessary condition* for understanding what he says.

I've marked the first sentence with a * because as far as formalizations go, this is an incorrect use of a conditional in normal logic, but it seems completely natural as English.

I mention this second example in part to state that similarity in the structure of the English alone is not enough to prove that the argument is fallacious.

Comment: Love this answer! It's really cool that you were able to see it as a formal fallacy because I never saw it as anything other than informal.